# Permission denied (publickey) - New computer, old key

Tags: ssh, debian, raspberry-pi-os

The situation is the following:
I have a raspberry pi, with authentication off, and a ssh key with passphrase.
The computer where I generated the ssh key doesn't work anymore, but I have backups of the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files.
I understand that simply copying these files to a new computer would not be very secure if this worked, but if my raspberry was not a physical device, but instead a cloud server, would I not be able to connect anymore? Everything would be lost? Can't I recover my access using the old keys and the passphrase? What is the good practice here? Always have a login authentication?

Edit:

To be more detailed about the steps I took and the error I'm getting, what I did was generation the keys on my old MacBook, and saved a backup of the d_rsa and id_rsa.pub files. I now have a new MacBook, where I copied the files to the .ssh folder. When I try to connect to my raspberry pi, running Debian, I get the following message:

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/caetano/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/Users/caetano/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions

Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: You say "doesn't work anymore" is meaningless. What is the error message? What did you do?

Comment: I've edit my question to specify everything I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "I understand that simply copying these files to a new computer would not be very secure" - I don't know where you got this idea.

You can (and should) copy the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on any computer you trust.
My keys have been installed on my 9 Pi and all the other computers I use on my local network for `ssh` & `ftp` access

You should copy the private key to any of your computers you want to connect from.
There is nothing to stop you having multiple private keys - I have several for different purposes, but use the same key on all my Pi.

The error message has the fix - key files should only be readable by the user i.e. `rw` permission for user `caetano` and read access for public keys but no access by others. If the keys are installed by the normal process `ssh-copy-id` this would be performed.

See https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id#copy-the-key-to-a-server

You will need to set the permissions manually.

```
-rw------- 1 1000 1000 1199 2018-11-05 13:33 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 1000 1000 1679 2018-11-12 13:37 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  399 2019-10-20 09:10 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 3770 2020-11-26 17:00 known_hosts
```

Comment: I've copied the key to the .ssh folder and I'm getting the error Permissions 0644 for '/Users/caetano/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open. It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will be ignored. Load key "/Users/caetano/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions

Comment: Changing the permissions of id_rsa.pub solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Typically, the permissions need to be: .ssh directory: 700 (drwx------), public key ( .pub files): 644 (-rw-r--r--), private key ( id_rsa ): 600 (-rw-------). After I changed the permissions with `sudo chmod 700 .ssh`, etc. all started working again. Thx